# Batch Script for Configure Game

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, shortcut-file

im trying to make a Batch Script under Windows . to stablish the Configurations of the game called "Ragnarok International".

And please dont tell "Simple Use Installer" because the idea of make this , its 1 learn batch , and two included in a personal autocontent version of "Ragnarok International" , that package , its for "Linux / Windows / Mac OS X" users . and i think its better included a Simple Script in Batch for Windows , to configure and make the Shortcuts.

Well im trying with the follow Code :

```
@echo off

color A
title Ragnarok International
set DIR="%CD%"
set PWD=%CD%\wine\data\drive_c\software

REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3 skip=4" %%i in (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop`) DO SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`ECHO %DESKTOPDIR%`) DO SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i
set IRODIR="%DESKTOPDIR%\Ragnarok International"



echo ===========Configuring Software=========
echo.

if exist     "%IRODIR%" (
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Classic.lnk" goto make_icr
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Classic Setup.lnk" goto make_ics
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Setup.lnk" goto make_setup
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Replay.lnk" goto make_replay
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok.lnk" goto make_ragnarok
)

cd "%DESKTOPDIR%
echo "Make the Directory"
If NOT exist "%IRODIR%" md "%IRODIR%" goto shortcuts

:shortcuts
echo.
echo "Make the Shorcuts"
echo.

:make_icr
echo "Ragnarok Classic"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Classic.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%\ClassicRO.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

:make_ics
echo "Classic Setup"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = %IRODIR%\Classic Setup.lnk >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%"\Setup_Classic.exe >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

:make_setup
echo "Setup"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = %IRODIR%\Setup.lnk >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%"\Setup.exe >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

:make_replay
echo "Ragnarok Replay"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = %IRODIR%\Ragnarok Replay.lnk >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%"\Ragexe.exe 1rag1 Replay >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%

:make_ragnarok
echo "Ragnarok"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = %IRODIR%\Ragnarok.lnk >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%"\Ragnarok.exe >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.
goto iro

echo ===========Configuring Software=========
pause

:iro
echo.
start /b %windir%\explorer.exe "%IRODIR%"
```

well , The Errors are in the first "if not exist" show me "and" its not reconized command or function (that its trying read the Path C:\Documents and Settings)

And the another fail , its when the script try to make the shorcuts :
C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\CONFIG~1\Temp\755-14902-9577-25159.vbs(2, 15) Microsoft VBS
cript compilation error: Expected end of statement

"Setup"
C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\CONFIG~1\Temp\31294-32230-10280-4385.vbs(2, 1) Microsoft VB
Script runtime error: Object required: 'Setup'

Well this are not working , someone can help me to fix the script . i dont know how to make it in Batch , for me its more ease Bash XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%i in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop^|findstr /C:"REG_SZ" /C:"REG_EXPAND_SZ"') DO SET "DESKTOPDIR=%%j"
```

I have no clue from VBS, sorry.

Additional, this is not correct:

```
If NOT exist "%IRODIR%" md "%IRODIR%" goto shortcuts
```

you can have only one command per line here:

```
If NOT exist "%IRODIR%" (
    md "%IRODIR%"
    goto shortcuts
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer , it seems the problem is that it fails to create the directory with md in the "if not" :

If NOT exist %IRODIR% cd "%DESKTOPDIR%" md "Ragnarok International" = "International" is not recognized as an internal or external command,program or batch file.

Some idea ???

Comment: DESKTOPDIR = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\Escritorio

Comment: @inukaze I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks , that help me too much , and the another thing i used in the final script is "echo oLink.Arguments = "1rag1 Replay" >> %SCRIPT%" for add parameters in the shortcut :D. Now all are working correctly :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all , This are SOLVED . the Batch Script the Final Code are the follow ->

```
@echo off

color A
title Ragnarok International
set DIR="%CD%"
set PWD=%CD%\wine\data\drive_c\software
C:
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop

FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%i in ('REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v Desktop^|findstr /C:"REG_SZ" /C:"REG_EXPAND_SZ"') DO SET "DESKTOPDIR=%%j"

FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`ECHO %DESKTOPDIR%`) DO SET DESKTOPDIR=%%i

set IRODIR=%DESKTOPDIR%\Ragnarok International



echo ===========Configuring Software=========
echo.
echo DESKTOPDIR = %DESKTOPDIR%
echo %IRODIR%


cd "%DESKTOPDIR%"
if exist     "%IRODIR%" ( echo.
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Classic.lnk" goto make_icr
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Classic Setup.lnk" goto make_ics
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Setup.lnk" goto make_setup
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Replay.lnk" goto make_replay
if not exist "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok.lnk" goto make_ragnarok
)

:shortcuts
echo.
echo "Make the Directory"
cd "%DESKTOPDIR%"
echo "Make the Shorcuts"

If NOT exist "%IRODIR%" (
    md "%IRODIR%"
    cd "%IRODIR%"
    goto shortcuts
    echo.
)
echo.

:make_icr
echo "Ragnarok Classic"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Classic.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%\ClassicRO.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

:make_ics
echo "Classic Setup"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%IRODIR%\Classic Setup.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%\Setup_Classic.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

:make_setup
echo "Setup"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%IRODIR%\Setup.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%\Setup.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

:make_replay
echo "Ragnarok Replay"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok Replay.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%\Ragexe.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Arguments = "1rag1 Replay" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%

:make_ragnarok
echo "Ragnarok"
set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"
echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%IRODIR%\Ragnarok.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%PWD%\Ragnarok.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%PWD%" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%
cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
echo.

echo ===========Configuring Software=========
goto iro

pause

:iro
echo.
start /b %windir%\explorer.exe "%IRODIR%"
```

That works perfect for this propose , thank you Endoro for help me with this script.